# Diagonal distance of two aircraft

Tags: gps, wgs84, haversine

I want to calculate the diagonal distance of two moving aircraft to estimate relative velocity.

Since the altitude and GPS position(longitude, latitude in decimal degrees WGS-84) of those two are different,

First I'll calculate the horizontal distance using haversine and calculate vertical distance by subtracting two altitude values.

Then, I thought using Pythagorean theorem will produce diagonal distance of those two aircraft.

But haversine is not a Euclidean distance (straight line).

In this case, how can I calculate the diagonal distance?

Comment: Is this assuming the two aircraft are far enough apart that a straight line path is not possible? Or that touching the surface of the geoid is okay or must you maintain an min. altitude while traversing between the two aircraft?

Comment: @RomaH I'm calculating the mean closing speed of all pairs of aircraft within a volume of airspace in order to esimate the conflict rate.  The altitudes of aircraft are all >=18000ft, some are cruising at constant speed, and some are climbing/descending. I'm trying to calculate the distance of pairs at each timestamp, so two aircraft can be far enough apart especially when they are diverging within the airspace.